# How do I get `apt-get update` to work on a machine with no internet access and manually assigned IP address?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, mirrors, apt-mirror

I have set up `apt-mirror` and downloaded the latest ubuntu packages successfully in a machine that can access the internet. The goal is to use this machine as the repository when doing `apt-get update` on the target machine that cannot access the internet. Both machines have been set up with manual IP addresses, and both machines are running with Ubuntu 16.04 as the OS. The `etc/apt/sources.list` in the target machine has only 1 line:

```
deb http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted multiverse universe
```

But when I do `sudo apt-get update` on the target machine, I get the following error:

```
Ign:1 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main InRelease
Ign:2 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main Release
Ign:3 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted all Packages
Ign:6 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en_HK
Ign:7 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en
Ign:8 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse all Packages
Ign:11 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en_HK
Ign:12 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:13 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en_HK
Ign:17 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en
Ign:3 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted all Packages
Ign:6 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en_HK
Ign:7 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en
Ign:8 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse all Packages
Ign:11 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en_HK
Ign:12 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:13 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en_HK
Ign:17 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en
Ign:3 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted all Packages
Ign:6 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en_HK
Ign:7 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en
Ign:8 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse all Packages
Ign:11 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en_HK
Ign:12 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:13 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en_HK
Ign:17 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en
Ign:3 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted all Packages
Ign:6 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en_HK
Ign:7 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en
Ign:8 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse all Packages
Ign:11 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en_HK
Ign:12 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:13 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en_HK
Ign:17 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en
Ign:3 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted all Packages
Ign:6 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en_HK
Ign:7 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en
Ign:8 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse all Packages
Ign:11 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en_HK
Ign:12 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:13 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe all Packages
Ign:16 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en_HK
Ign:17 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe Translation-en
Err:3 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:4 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted all Packages
Ign:6 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en_HK
Ign:7 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted Translation-en
Ign:8 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse all Packages
Ign:11 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en_HK
Ign:12 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:13 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/universe amd64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial/dists/main/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

On the target machine:

1. The `/etc/resolve.conf` file contains the following:

   ```
   # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
   #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
   nameserver 127.0.1.1
   ```
2. The `/etc/network/interfaces` contains the following:

   ```
   # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
   ```

Also, since the only line in the output of `apt-get update` that explicitly says error is `Err:3 http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial main/restricted amd64 Packages`, I checked if the file exists by doing the following in the target machine

`wget http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages`

And I see that the file is there, as I get the following output:

```
--2017-12-21 17:23:24--  http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages
Connecting to <local_repo_IP>:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 127112 (124K)
Saving to: ‘Packages’

Packages                100%[============================>] 124.13K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-12-21 17:23:24 (469 MB/s) - ‘Packages’ saved [127112/127112]
```

I also checked to see if I can ping successfully from the target machine to the repo machine. That works out too.

```
PING <local_repo_IP> (<local_repo_IP>) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from <local_repo_IP>: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.169 ms
64 bytes from <local_repo_IP>: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.671 ms
64 bytes from <local_repo_IP>: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.186 ms
64 bytes from <local_repo_IP>: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.190 ms
64 bytes from <local_repo_IP>: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.315 ms
^C
--- <local_repo_IP> ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4047ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.169/0.306/0.671/0.190 ms
```

So, what is wrong with `apt-get update`? How can I fix it and get it to work?

**P.S.** I just noticed that the error says `http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial/dists/main/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages`. Why is it trying to look for `restricted` packages inside main? Shouldn't it be looking in `http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages`? Indeed when I do `wget http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial/dists/main/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages`, it gives the following error:

```
--2017-12-21 17:26:06--  http://<local_repo_IP>/ubuntu/dists/xenial/dists/main/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages
Connecting to <local_repo_IP>:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-12-21 17:26:06 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

What's going on here? Why is it trying to check for a non-existing directory? And how do I make `apt-get update` point to the correct path?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the solution to be to edit the `etc/apt/sources.list` file to include files of only the system's architecture:

`deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted multiverse universe`

Now when I do the update, its not giving any error:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Just thought of posting this as a possible solution for anyone who might be having the same issue.

Comment: Posting an answer to your own question is absolutely the right way to do it. On behalf of the people who will find this in the future, thanks!

Comment: You can also mark this as the solution.

Comment: I don't think this is what actually solved your problem, considering that what you got an error for was an `amd64` file, and restricting *to `amd64`* would hardly make it go away. Is this the only change you made to `sources.list` or to other related configuration? Did you resync your mirror before this change was made?

Comment: I agree with @topher.  You should mark this as a solution.

Comment: @muru Yes, this is the only change I made, and its not giving any error after that. And yeah, I agree with you that it *should* not solved the issue. So, any ideas as to why it worked? Also, I noticed that the path it was trying to search in (in the error) is wrong - it should search in `http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages`, but it was searching in `http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/dists/xenial/dists/main/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages`. Why would that be? And how did specifying the architecture solve that issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

my take on the [amd-64]...If let's say, for example, in your /etc/apt/sources.list you have enabled the google chrome updates
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

you can see that is the only entry that has the [amd-64] in it, and it's from a google source.

In your first initial mention of "deb http://192...", maybe your updates got stalled when it got to the sources.list mention of the chrome update, since it wasn't specifically mentioned as such.

Or, look at *sudo apt-cache policy*, sources.list and sources.list.d

Eventually, I may venture out and replicate this in my own lab, before I answer further.